# Find intersection of words from two list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, intersection

I have two list of strings as:

```
a = ['ketab khaneh','danesh gah', 'shi rin i']

b = ['ketab khaneh','dan esh gah','shirin i']
```

I need the intersection of individual words from the list. For example, for above lists, my desired output is:

```
output = ['ketab','khaneh','gah','i']
```

How I can produce this output in python?

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: That isn't the intersection of two lists

Comment: I have tried this: l=set(s1.split()) & set(s2.split()). But this code finds some of intersections,not all of them. @jonrsharpe

Comment: The problem is your definition of "intersection", not with the code

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of a case that doesn't work.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Really? sorry, my English isnt good. I thought its name is the intersection. anyway, Could you help me with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) with [`itertools.chain()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) as:

```
>>> from itertools import chain

>>> a=['ketab khaneh','danesh gah', 'shi rin i']
>>> b=['ketab khaneh','dan esh gah','shirin i']

>>> set(chain(*map(str.split, a))).intersection(chain(*map(str.split, b)))
set(['i', 'khaneh', 'ketab', 'gah'])
```

Comment: use `chain.from_iterable`, which I usually just use as `flatten = chain.from_iterable`

Comment: I initially used `.from_iterable` (which is in my edit) but then realised that we any way need to completely exhaust the iterable. So lazy evaluation of from_iterable is not giving us any benefit

Comment: it avoids the needless creation of an intermediate tuple. Probably not a big deal

Answer (score 2):

use `set` intersection method

```py
a = " ".join(a).split(" ")
b = " ".join(b).split(" ")
output = list(set(a).intersection(b))
```

output

```
['ketab', 'khaneh', 'gah', 'i']
```

Comment: No need to turn `b` into a set. You can pass any iterable to `set.intersection`.

Comment: Yes that is true but if one use `&` operator then it is required. As a good practise I kept it. Will it increase the `complexity`?

Comment: No, the general complexity is the same. You lose some best case performance as you iterate `b` completely all the time.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It is true that in order to apply `set`, we need to iterate all the elements. But if it like `a = (1,2,3)` and `b = (1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3)` then in that case using `set` will increase the time complexity.